# Git pull on multiple servers

Tags: git, github, chef-infra, githooks

I have a web app on Github whose servers are provisioned with Hosted Chef server and Cloudformation.  After searching the net for the last couple of hours with no luck, can someone give some insight how to do a git pull for the app directed to  multiple servers(all redundant) using Chef.  Essentially, the apps master branch pulled into each server where the number of servers is known by chef server.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "manually" pull changes, you probably need to write a [knife ssh](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html) command. You can use it like:

```
$ knife ssh SEARCH_QUERY SSH_COMMAND (options)
```

or in your case:

```
$ knife ssh "role:web" "cd my_app && git pull"
```

If you want to do that on regular basis, you need to create cookbook which will be part of your nodes run lists, and then trigger chef client on every node:

```
$ knife ssh "role:web" "sudo chef-client"
```

or do it automatically by running chef-client as a daemon.

```
$ sudo chef-client -d --interval SECONDS
```

Comment: Thanks Rastasheep for your reply, it make good sense.  Question, in running the command "knife ssh "role:web" "cd my_app && git pull""  what does it mean if you get

WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-30-34.us-west-2.compute.internal 

WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-43-208.us-west-2.compute.internal 

WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-36-181.us-west-2.compute.internal

WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-1-220.us-west-2.compute.internal 

I noticed chef server has 172-31.x.x respectively for each node as each line above.  However, the public ip's are actually different.

Comment: (Continue) Seems like I have would need to have chef-client detect the connection settings on the node and resend to Chef Server.

Comment: That command queries chef server for attributes and with them tries to ssh into each one (from results of that query) and execute desired command. By default it uses FQDN node attribute instead of IP address for SSH. You can change that by `-a SSH_ATTR` option like `knife ssh "role:web" "sudo chef-client" -a ipaddress` (you can specify any node attribute there). You can also specify user which will be used for SSH-ing with `-x USER_NAME` or port with `-p PORT`. [Check docs](https://docs.chef.io/knife_ssh.html) for full list of options.

Comment: "FATAL: 4 nodes found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute. "   I've tried diffent combinations of attributes,  sudo knife ssh "role:web" "touch /home/ubuntu/testfile.txt" --attribute 54.68.122.109 -i /Users/useraccount/.ssh/mykey.pem -x ubuntu     Not sure why its giveing the error?  I am able to ssh into it.

Comment: Attribute should be node attribute name, not actual value, knife will replace name with values for every node returned by chef server

Comment: This may be the correct solution, though I'm still running into the same with knife ssh'n into the ec2 instances. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364287/warning-failed-to-connect-to-ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear to me what you wish to do so i will answer both:

1. Pull changes on multiple servers once you pushed them to git hub
2. Pull changes from different servers from git hub

---

1. **Multiple remotes**

   If you need to pull/push code to multiple repositories you simply need to add multiple **[`remotes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)** to your git repository.
2. In order to pull changes from git hub to multiple servers read about github **[webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)** and how to **[configure your server](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/)** to support it. you   will to use **[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)**

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I was thinking of it in your first question, "Pull changes on multiple servers once you pushed them to git hub."  However, its possible to think of the second too.  However, do you think it would work somehow involving Chef Server, Knife, Chef Roles, and cookbooks?  I'm still a bit new :|

Comment: I know what is chef and i used as part of our deployment environment but i have no experience in writing chef recipes or cookbooks so i can help you here. i do know git very well (im lecturing in seminar and courses about git) so i can help you will all the git related stuff. but if i understand you correctly the second option should work for you, install ngrok and open the right ports. then github will "sync" your repos

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking that you could use the [chef deploy](https://docs.chef.io/resource_deploy.html) resource.  The only tricky part about the deploy resource is the ssh wrapper that is required to authenticate to git.

Then I would do:

```
knife ssh 'name:somepattern' 'chef-client'
```