# WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

**Error: FATAL: # nodes found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.**

The issue I'm having started with attempting to run a command using the chef knife command.  The intent is to have the command run on any server part of the role as you'll see.

So, when I run the command I get the following I get the following

```
knife ssh "role:servers" "touch /home/ubuntu/file.txt"

WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-8-x.us-west-2.compute.internal -- SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-94-xb.us-west-2.compute.internal -- SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
WARNING: Failed to connect to ip-172-31-99-x.us-west-2.compute.internal -- SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

When I try new attributes

```
knife ssh "role:web" "touch /home/ubuntu/file.txt" -x ubuntu -a hostname

FATAL: 6 nodes found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the 
connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.
```

I tried differnet attributes but with no luck

```
knife ssh "role:servers" "touch /home/ubuntu/file.txt" -a ec2.public_hostname
knife ssh "role:servers" "touch /home/ubuntu/file.txt" -a public_hostname


knife ssh "role:servers" "touch /home/ubuntu/testfile.txt" --attribute 54.68.122.109 -i /Users/useraccount/.ssh/mykey.pem -x ubuntu

FATAL: 2 nodes found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute.
```

Clearly I'm missing something.

I should note that I am able to ssh into the servers but not by using the ip-172-31-x-x.us-west-2.compute.internal that chef-clients detect at provisioning, rather, the AWS Public IP.

Would this affect my being able to run the command above properly?

Chef server lists node data as

**FQDN**: ip-172-31-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal

**IP Address**: 172.31.xx.xx

With AWS setting matching like so,

**Priviate DNS** :ip-172-31-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.internal

**Priviate IPs** : 172.31.xx.xx

However, the information AWS for sshing into the an instance is

**Public DNS** : ec2-54-200-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
**Public IP**  : 54.200.xx.xxx

It's the AWS Public DNS data I can use to properly ssh into a server(non knife).

If it's possible the issue is the way chef-client provisions node data into chef server, is there away to correct it so chef server reflects the nodes aws public ip data?

Comment: See comments on second answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/641951/knife-cant-ssh-into-newly-instantiated-ec2-server

Comment: They maybe the case if was using knife to create the ec2 server, however, I'm using the automated install option where chef-client -j /etc/chef/mynodes.json detects the instance settings then adds itself to chef server.  Here is where the issue may be.  The FQDN and IP Address are showing incorrect.  Im thinking they should show to the public DNS name and IP address.  So if this is the case, would nice to know how chef-clinet adds this information.   Looking at chef-clinet, can't see how to pass in the public info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your workstation is on an AWS VPN, or actually running inside your VPC, you'll want to use `-a public_ip_address`.

If this is a VPC instance, it is possible that you don't have that attribute set due to some issues with `ohai`.  In this case, make sure that you set the ec2 hint for `ohai`.  The easiest way to do so is to use the `--hint ec2` flag when you bootstrap the node.

Finally, if this node doesn't have a public ip address, as many don't in a VPC, then you'll need to use a proxy node to reach it.  `--ssh-gateway` flag is used for this, and would need to point to a node in the public subnet of your VPC.

Comment: Thanks Tejay.  I'm still running into the same issue.

I referenced this doc page and I couldn't find the --hint ec2 you mentioned
[link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/knife-ssh.1.html)

When I do try the --hint ec2 option I get

_"Error: invalid option: --hint"_

Next, I did a command mentioned in the man page to run on all EC2 web servers and I got the same error message as this topic.

 -x ubuntu -a ec2.public_hostname

Comment: The `--hint` is added to the `bootstrap` command, not the `ssh` command.   It ensures that the node will set the `node[:public_ip_address]` attribute.

Comment: I'm using [unattended install](http://docs.chef.io/client/install_bootstrap.html)  chef-client -j /etc/chef/mynodes.json to run the command.  After this, the node adds itself to chef server.   However, can't seem to figure this knife ssh thing

Comment: Then you'll need to manually add the ec2 hint another way.  Either by simply adding an empty file at `/etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json`  (the file can be completely blank), or by using the oahi cookbook https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ohai

Comment: Thanks Tejay!  Adding the file /etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json, then re-running chef client to re-staple it self worked.

Comment: Then, back on the command line ran ``knife ssh "role:servers" "touch /home/ubuntu/file.txt" -a ec2.public_hostname -x ubuntu -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem`` worked~